# React Native - How to Redirect to a login view from componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to detect if a user is logged in during an application start and redirect him to a login screen if not logged in.

```
import * as AuthView from '../modules/auth/AuthView';    
const AppView = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        isReady: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        snapshotUtil.resetSnapshot()
            .then(snapshot => {
                const {dispatch} = this.props;

                if (snapshot) {
                    dispatch(SessionStateActions.resetSessionStateFromSnapshot(snapshot));
                } else {
                    dispatch(SessionStateActions.initializeSessionState());
                }

                store.subscribe(() => {
                    snapshotUtil.saveSnapshot(store.getState());
                });
            });
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps({isReady, isLoggedIn}) {
        if (!this.props.isReady) {
            if (isReady && !isLoggedIn) {
                console.warn("Not logged in, trying to show login screen here...");
               AuthView.showLoginView();
            }
        }
    },

    render() {
        if (!this.props.isReady) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator style={styles.centered}/>
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <NavigationViewContainer />
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

And my AuthView Looks like this:

```
export function showLoginView() {
    var loginView = <View>
        <Text>
            This is a Login View
        </Text>
    </View>;

    return loginView;
}
```

The output is blank . looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7y6u.png

So it is showing the warning message ( console.warn ) and showing the "ActivityIndicator" . But not a Login Panel.

My question is, how to I modify the showLoginView() function to show a full screen login view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show all views within your render() function. If you develop a complex application consider use Navigator component.
In your case:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps({isReady, isLoggedIn}) {
    if (!this.props.isReady) {
        if (isReady && !isLoggedIn) {
            console.warn("Not logged in, trying to show login screen here...");
           this.state.showLogin = true;
        }
    }
 },
 render() {
    if (this.state.showLogin) {
        return showLoginView()
    } 
    if (!this.props.isReady) {
        return (
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator style={styles.centered}/>
```

...

Comment: I was about to come to same conclusion ! thankyou for confirming. i shall wait and see if there is any other way to do it . btw, the code i pasted is part of pepperoni-app-kit which i am trying to understand. they are doing something similar : https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit/blob/master/src/modules/AppView.js#L36 . However, it looks like it uses native module for rendering the login at that line

Answer (score 1):

I have similar code. The props in the below code come from Redux. So, I am directly using props instead of state.

```
  render() {
    return this.props.account.loggedIn ?
    <Main
    /> :
    <Login
      onLogin={this.props.onLogin}
    />;
  }
```